# Static DataTable method with parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to bind an asp repeater with a sql query, that includes a parameter but im using a public Static method, so i dont know how to pass a variable to this method :

Code behind aspx webfile :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.DataAdmin();           
}

public void DataAdmin()
{
    /****Resultado is the repeater name    */
    Datatable dataAdmin = DescargarDocumentos.SolicitarDatosDocumento() ;
    Resultados.DataSource = dataAdmin;
    Resultados.DataBind();
}
```

Code behind the class

```
public class DescargaDocumentos
{

    public static DataTable SolicitarDatosDocumentos()
    {
        /* */
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conexion"].ConnectionString);
        SqlDataReader reader;
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand vistadocumentos = new SqlCommand("ultimasolicitud", conn);
        vistadocumentos.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

         /* i need to add the parameter here */
        vistadocumentos.Parameters.AddWithValue("@numero",numero);/*error is here because i cant get pass this parameter to a static method*/
        reader = vistadocumentos.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable test = null;
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            test = new DataTable("test");
            test.Load(reader);
        }
        reader.Close();
        conn.Close();
        return test;
    }
}
```

The error is on the variable number because i cant "pass the variable numero" to a static method, is it possible to do it?

btw this is the stored procedure (should return file names according to the order number)

```
alter  procedure documentlist (
           @numero int
)
as
begin
    select 
    tipo_de_documento.tipo_documento,detalle_documentos.nombre_documento 
    from tipo_de_documento inner join has_tipo on 
    tipo_de_documento.numero=has_tipo.numero_tipo inner join 
    detalle_documentos 
    on has_tipo.id_detalle= detalle_documentos.id_detalle inner join 
    Documentos 
    on detalle_documentos.num_documento= documentos.num_documento where 
    documentos.num_solicitud=@numero

end
```

Comment: Where do you declare the variable _numero_. Why don't you simply pass it to your method as parameter?

Comment: when i try to pass as a normal parameter im getting an error.

Comment: This isn't your issue, but you're using your SqlConnection wrong. It implement [IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx) and you need to follow the correct practices for disposing it.

Comment: What error? Where are you passing it? You need to be specific about what your issue is.

Comment: Please show the code where you define the variable _numero_ and how do you initialize it and show your attempt to pass this variable to the static method

Comment: If you want to pass something to a method, you add a *method parameter*.

Comment: @mason what's a good implemention for this? im kinda new to ASP

Comment: Read the link I provided you for starters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should specify "which document" should be searched, maybe from a textbox.

I suggest the following changes:

```
int numeroDocumento;
if (!int.TryParse(txtNumeroDocumento.Text, out numeroDocumento))
{
    //Something here to sinalize that the "numeroDocumento" is not a number.
    return;
} 
Datatable dataAdmin = DescargarDocumentos.SolicitarDatosDocumento(numeroDocumento);
```

and

```
public static DataTable SolicitarDatosDocumentos(int numero)
//You need to make that method accept the "number" arg
```

Also I suggest you to translate your variable names from portuguese/spanish to english when posting here.

1. Número means Number
2. Documento means Document
3. Tipo de Documento means DocumentType
4. Vista means View
5. Detalhe means Details
6. Descarregar means "Download/Load/something simillar"
7. UltimaSolicitação means LastRequest

Comment: Cannot convert type 'string' to 'int'

Comment: You must be sure that you do have an Id to search. The textbox value can't be empty, or "twelve" instead of "12".

You could  do the following:  
int numeroDocumento;
if (!int.TryParse(txtNumeroDocumento.Text, numeroDocumento))
{
    //Something here to sinalize that the "numeroDocumento" is not a number.//
    return;
}

Comment: You haven't understood my comment. I mean. The code in your answer is wrong and doesn't compile at all. C# doesn't allow a cast like this _(int)"12"_ It is not just a matter of validation.

Comment: You are right. Just edited from casting to parsing, as C# default is strict.